# Updating a single column in a table

Tags: t-sql

I have a table for Inventory Dollars by Vendor by Month.  I want to be able to update the dollar amounts for the current month on a daily basis, but I don't want to lose the previous month's data.  Here is the basic query I have:

```
DELETE Inventory_Dollars 
FROM Inventory_Summary
WHERE MonthNum = '4'

SELECT
SUM(Cost*OnHand) AS Inventory_Dollars
FROM Inventory
```

The Inventory table will always hold the current data.  How can I just Insert Into Inventory_Summary the data from the Select statement?

Answer (score 0):

Just preface your query with an INSERT:

```
INSERT INTO Inventory_Summary
            (Inventory_Dollars)
SELECT SUM(Cost * OnHand) AS Inventory_Dollars
FROM   Inventory
```

Comment: But I need it to go into the MonthNum column

Comment: Perhaps I don't quite understand.  Do you need a MonthNum to go along with it, or does the Inventory_Dollars query go directly into the MonthNum column?  Forgive me for asking, but the latter sounds a bit counter intuitive.

Comment: The current layout of the Inventory_Summary table is this:  Year, MonthNum, Inventory_Dollars.  I want to delete the current month's data daily and insert the latest data into the current MonthNum.

Answer (score 0):

If you've already inserted the inventory_dollars amount for the current month, you can then update the value every day with something like this:

```
UPDATE Inventory_Summary
SET Inventory_Dollars = (
    SELECT (Cost * OnHand)
    FROM Inventory
)
WHERE MonthNum = DATEPART(m, GETDATE()) AND Year = DATEPART(year, GETDATE())
```

The DATEPART can be used to fill in the number of the month for the current date, GETDATE().  Then you won't be updating the inventory_dollars values for past months.

Edit: Also added a year to the where clause, so you don't update months from past years.

Edit 2: If you use a subquery in the SET, make sure only one result can come back.

Comment: I still need to DELETE first, right?  Also, I'm not updating Inventory.  That is the table where I get the current data.  Inventory_Summary is the table I need updated.

Comment: Nope, update will replace whatever is in the Inventory_Dollars column, as long as you already have a value in there that also matches on the MonthNum and Year columns.

Comment: Also some interesting reading on doing an upsert, which will do an INSERT if you don't have a matching row, and an UPDATE if you do: http://samsaffron.com/blog/archive/2007/04/04/14.aspx

Comment: The SET statement needs to have a SUM and I get an error.  An aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement.

Comment: That just deleted all my previous months and updated month 4 with all the same bad data...

Comment: Make sure that WHERE clause is in there, and why do you need the SUM?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28687/discussion-between-tsqln00b-and-sean-fahey)